# How do I use an indeterminate status indicator as the image for an NSStatusItem?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsstatusitem

I have an application that is an `NSStatusItem`.

It has a few different modes, each of which require an external process to be launched, during which the icon is simply highlighted, and appears to be frozen.

I want to use the `-setImage:` method (or reasonable facsimile) to display something along the lines of a "spinner" commonly seen in web applications and all over OS X.

Is there any native method for accomplishing this (e.g. some instance of `NSProgressIndicator`?) or must I manually display an animation by cycling through a set of images?

In either case, how would I implement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to have it be animated (and not just a static image), you'll probably need to use `-setView:` and give it a custom view (which then animates itself).  You might be able to get away with using a suitably-configured standard `NSProgressIndicator` (i.e. set to `NSProgressIndicatorSpinningStyle` style, etc.) as that "custom view".

But, if the NSProgressIndicator standard sizes don't work well, then you can check out my [YRKSpinningProgressIndicator](http://github.com/kelan/yrk-spinning-progress-indicator) (BSD-licensed), which is a clone of the spinning NSProgressIndicator that can be set to arbitrary size and colors.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to be able to get away with using an NSProgressIndicator.