# Progress spinner in status bar in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'd like to create a `NSStatusItem` that displays a progress spinner.  My idea was to subclass `NSProgressIndicator` and use this as a `NSView` to pass to `setView:`.

```
// SpinnerView.h
//#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface SpinnerView : NSProgressIndicator {
    NSStatusItem *_statusItem;
    BOOL _isHighlighted;
}
- (id)initWithStatusItem:(NSStatusItem *)statusItem;
@end    

// SpinnerView.m
#import "SpinnerView.h"

@implementation SpinnerView

- (id)initWithStatusItem:(NSStatusItem *)statusItem {
    CGFloat thickness = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] thickness];
    NSRect frameRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, thickness, thickness);
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    [self setStyle:NSProgressIndicatorSpinningStyle];
    [self setControlSize:NSSmallControlSize];
    _statusItem = statusItem;
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    NSLog(@"drawRect");
    [_statusItem drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect:dirtyRect withHighlight:_isHighlighted];
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}

@end
```

However, when I do this, the spinner is displayed but is surrounded by a white box:

[image: Spinner in status bar]

Any idea why this happens, or how to fix it?  If I comment out the entire `drawRect:` method the result is the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714951

Answer (score 0):

You need to just continually set the image for the status item.
 Use a timer.

Comment: Not what I'm asking.  I want to use `NSProgressIndicator`, not write my own.